# 2.chunk.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'item')

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on an Angular 13 project with Angular Material and have gotten this error

```
2.chunk.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'item')
at ha (tabPrompt.chunk.js:1:3252851)
at Xo (2.chunk.js:1:260619)
at ji (2.chunk.js:1:267476)
at Ii (2.chunk.js:1:274220)
at Va (2.chunk.js:1:298431)
at qa (2.chunk.js:1:298815)
at Pu (2.chunk.js:1:305712)
at ju (2.chunk.js:1:305092)
at Eu (2.chunk.js:1:304113)
at Ja (2.chunk.js:1:302987)
```

I removed the most recent chuck of code I added and still got the error mentioned above.
I tried going through and removing any code that was questionable but I still got that error! I don't understand what is happening and cannot find where the error is coming from. Someone, please help me!

Comment: I got this using react in chrome. no idea why

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just in case other people come across this, in my case it was LastPass that was throwing this error in my console.

Comment: Same thing here!

Comment: Same here. Tried in a new browser without LastPass, everything works fine.

Comment: This was helpful.  For me, I ended up disabling then re-enabling the browser extension.  After that, everything worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a different browser (in my case I went from chrome to Firefox) and it helped. A few hours later I went back to chrome and it worked again and I didn’t get this error! I don’t know what the issue is but this seems to have fixed it!